# CRIT 005 Error on outputChannelCreateTx

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I'm new to this hyperledger and was trying to setup my first network.
I tried to create a channel transaction artifact using the command given on official docs of hyperledger :

**export CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel  && ../bin/configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputCreateChannelTx ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME**

But I'm getting an error:

**CRIT 005 Error on outputChannelCreateTx:** config update generation failure: could not parse application to application group: setting up the MSP manager failed: the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: ECDSA verification failure" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "ca.org1.example.com")

Comment: How did you generate the cryptographic material used by your channel config?

Comment: @GariSingh buddy I've been following the instructions on the official hyperledger website.
And I was setting up my first network by following the instructions from this link https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/build_network.html